# Name [ejb:..] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [ejb: ].] with root cause javax.naming.NameNotFoundException in Wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, wildfly, jndi

I am trying to call my EJBs in a remote environment and I am using Wildfly as my container.

Apologies but this is my first time trying to call an EJBs in a remote way.

I have used the instructions below for invoking EJBs in Wildfly.
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

But, I am having an error calling these EJBs and I do not know what is wrong to my configuration.

See error stack trace below:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/Project-demo] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [ejb: /ImageService-1.0-SNAPSHOT//GrayscaleImageServiceImpl!com.project.imageservice.ImageManipulateService] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [ejb: ].] with root cause
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [ejb: /ImageService-1.0-SNAPSHOT//GrayscaleImageServiceImpl!com.project.imageservice.ImageManipulateService] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [ejb: ].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.sketchy.remote.context.RemoteContext.lookupRemoteGrayscaleService(RemoteContext.java:30)
    at com.sketchy.controllers.ServiceController.grayscaleService(ServiceController.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My interface in both remote server and client side:

```
public interface ImageManipulateService{
    public UploadedImage manipulate(UploadedImage img) throws IOException, Exception;
}
```

My EJB in the remote server (Wildfly):

```
@Service
@Stateless
@Remote(ImageManipulateService.class)
public class GrayscaleImageServiceImpl implements ImageManipulateService{

    @Override
    public Object manipulate(Object img) throws IOException, Exception {
        ....
    }

}
```

[image]

Client side:

> jboss-ejb-client.properties

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false

remote.connections=default

remote.connection.default.host = localhost
remote.connection.default.port = 9090
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

I have been running my client in tomcat server (:8080) and I'm trying to invoke the EJBs on Wildfly via localhost:9090. (is it correct?)

> I also have the jboss-client.jar included in my Maven dependencies. I
>   used version 4.0.2. (jboss-client-4.0.2.jar)

I made a java class that would call the lookup of services in order to conveniently call them.

```
public class RemoteContext {

    public static ImageManipulateService lookupRemoteGrayscaleService() throws NamingException {
        Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
        jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

        String appName = "";
        String moduleName = "ImageService-1.0-SNAPSHOT";
        String distinctName = "";
        String beanName = "GrayscaleImageServiceImpl";
        String viewClassName = "com.project.imageservice.ImageManipulateService";

        return (ImageManipulateService) context.lookup("ejb: " + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "!" + viewClassName);
    }

    public static ImageManipulateService lookupRemoteTimestampService() throws NamingException {
        Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
        jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

        String appName = "";
        String moduleName = "ImageService-1.0-SNAPSHOT";
        String distinctName = "";
        String beanName = "TimestampImageServiceImpl";
        String viewClassName = "com.project.imageservice.ImageManipulateService";

        return (ImageManipulateService) context.lookup("ejb: " + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "!" + viewClassName);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem here is that you're using the wrong `jboss-client.jar`. The one you have selected is for JBoss 4.0.x and will not work at all with WildFly.

If you're building with Maven then you would include the following dependency in your client application (being the war project):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>10.1.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

But since you don't appear to be using Maven, the alternative is to add the `jboss-client.jar` that you will find in the `bin/client/` directory of your WildFly installation. It's an "uber-jar" containing everything that is defined by the maven dependency shown above.

Once you have this sorted out you might need some help with the JNDI name. We will be able to fix that with the deployment output from your `server.log`, which records all of your EJB application's JNDI names.

Comment: I am using maven and I include the artifact id jboss-client with version 4.0.2 since I thought that it is just the same with jboss-client that resides in the wildfly directory. This is to set my dependencies only in Maven.

I'll try this and let you know if it works.

Comment: **EJBCLIENT000037: Could not load ejb proxy class com.project.imageservice.ImageManipulateService** error has shown. The error above now is not showing. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to ensure that your client side application has access to the `ImageManipulateService` class plus any other of your classes that it uses (such as `UploadedImage`). Normally I create an "API" module that holds all of these classes that both the client and server depend upon.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll tag this as an answer since it resolves the first issue.

Comment: I'm happy to assist if you're still struggling

Answer (score 1):

If you EJB is deployed in a war, then the application name in the JNDI name should be *empty*. Although your `appName` variable holds an empty string, you have a space character after "ejb:". Remove this space such that it is like in the documentation:

```
ejb:/jboss-as-ejb-remote-app//CalculatorBean!org.jboss.as.quickstarts.ejb.remote.stateless.RemoteCalculator
```

Comment: thanks for noticing but the error is still the same. My EJBs were not deployed in a war project but rather in a jar file.